# Someone guesses a number, using only $\gt, \lt$ or $=$ as responses to questions attempting to determine the number.

Tags: combinatorics

Alice and Bob play the following game: Alice thinks of a number from 0 to 2000 which Bob must guess with the least number of tries. To do so, each time he writes in a piece of paper one question which Alice must reply by using only “>”, “<” or “=”. If the question set from Bob does not precisely accept one of the 3 above signs, then Bob loses this challenge and has to ask a new question. What is the least number of tries (questions) required so that Bob guesses the number, no matter how unlucky he is, and what are the questions he must ask?

I believe he must ask the below questions:
How is the number related to 1000?
If the answer is =,we are done.
If the answer is >, then he asks 
How is the number related to 1500?
Otherwise,
How is the number related to 500?
Then we continue after 1500-1750-1875-1938-1969 and so on… or respectively, according to the reply given.
Does this work?
Any better ideas?

Comment: Yes it works, you described the binary search algorithm which has a complexity of O(log(n))

Comment: I agree with the first comment and just want to add that 2^11=2048 so the maximum number of 'searches' would be 11.

Comment: The question can be.  "If the number is betwee 1 and 667 answer <; if between 668 and 1333 answer =; or if between 1334 and 2000 answer >".  Each question reduces the options by a third so.....

Comment: "yes it works, you described the binary search algorithm" but as three answers are possible, we can do a *tri*nary search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within $k$ questions, there will only be $3^k$ possible known outcomes so Bob can not determine which of more then $3^6 = 729$ options is correct in $6$ or fewer questions.  So no strategy can guarentee success in fewer than $7$ questions.

But the following strategy *will* guarantee success in exactly $7$ questions.

"If we wrote this number in base $3$ it would be a $7$ digit number $a_6a_5a_4a_3a_2a_1a_0$ somewhere between $0000001_3 = 1$ and $2202001=2000$.

"My $7$ question are going to be:

"Question no. $i$.  Is $a_{i- 1}$ less than, equal to, or more than $1$?"

That way within $7$ questions Bob will know the value of all the digits of the number in base $3$ and thus Bob will know the number.

Answer (score 0):

How does $(x-3)(x-6)(x-9)...(x-1998)$ compare to $0$ ?

Comment: This is indeed a question that can be answered with one of the three symbols. The answer does give you interesting information. How would you use it to proceed to guess the number (in no more than $11$ steps)?

Comment: So "=" means it is a multiple of 3.  That's nice.  What does < or > give you and what to you ask next.

Comment: Actually you are onto something.  But you need to formulate what the next 6 questions need to be.